# Setting temp outliers (by month) at each latitude-longitude pair to NAN with xarray

Tags: python-xarray

I'm looking at the [CPC tmax data](https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/cpc_global_temp/) and am trying to apply a simple outlier detection function at each latitude-longitude pair for each month. I load in all the yearly nc files using `xr.open_mfdataset(file_ls, combine = 'nested', concat_dim = "time")`, which looks like the following:

[image: Overview of data]

I have what I think is a pretty basic outlier detection function that uses the max and min temperatures recorded on Earth for absolute thresholds and then uses all temperature data at a latitude-longitude pair for that month and Tukey's Fences method to identify other outliers. The function requires an entire month's data at a latitude-longitude pair and returns a list the same size as the input, just with any outliers set to np.NAN.

```
def simple_out(temp_dat):
 RECORD_HI  = 57
 RECORD_LOW = -90
 TUKEY_MULT = 3

 temp_dat = temp_dat.tmax.values

 # Drop the NAs and look for outliers to remove
 no_na_ls = temp_dat[~np.isnan(temp_dat)]

 # Calculate median and  IQR for tukey
 pre_med = np.nanmedian(no_na_ls)
 iqr = np.quantile(no_na_ls, 0.75) - np.quantile(no_na_ls, 0.25)

 OUTLIER_MIN_THRESH = pre_med - (TUKEY_MULT * iqr)
 OUTLIER_MAX_THRESH = pre_med + (TUKEY_MULT * iqr)

 ret_ls = []

 for curr_temp in no_na_ls:
     if not ((curr_temp > RECORD_HI) or (curr_temp < RECORD_LOW) or
           (curr_temp > OUTLIER_MAX_THRESH) or (curr_temp < OUTLIER_MIN_THRESH)):
        
         ret_ls.append(curr_temp)
 return ret_ls
```

I've tried to think of how to use groupby(time.month) with apply/map or apply_ufunc but I just can't figure out how to actually write the code to apply this function how I'm wanting to. Could someone with more experience with xarray help me out with how to apply this function to the data in the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep - you're definitely on the right track! when you use `da.groupby()`, a [`DataArrayGroupBy`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.groupby.DataArrayGroupBy.html) object is returned, and you can check out the available methods on that class's API documentation. The function I think you're looking for is `map`: see [`DataArrayGroupBy.map`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.groupby.DataArrayGroupBy.map.html).

I'd make a couple tweaks to your function so it returns a DataArray of the same shape as the inputs:

```py
def simple_out(temp_dat):
    RECORD_HI  = 57
    RECORD_LOW = -90
    TUKEY_MULT = 3

    # in a N-D DataArray, this actually doesn't do anything
    # as the NaN cells can't be dropped individually, so I've
    # commented the next line out. quantile in xarray
    # skips NaNs by default so you're ok ignoring this.
    # no_na_ls = temp_dat[~np.isnan(temp_dat)]

    # Calculate median and  IQR for tukey
    qs = temp_dat.quantile([0.25, 0.5, 0.75], dim='time')
    pre_med = qs.sel(quantile=0.5)
    iqr = qs.sel(quantile=0.75) - qs.sel(quantile=0.25)

    OUTLIER_MIN_THRESH = pre_med - (TUKEY_MULT * iqr)
    OUTLIER_MAX_THRESH = pre_med + (TUKEY_MULT * iqr)

    # apply conditions to all cells at once with DataArray.where
    return temp_dat.where(
        (temp_dat <= RECORD_HI)
        & (temp_dat >= RECORD_LOW)
        & (temp_dat >= OUTLIER_MIN_THRESH)
        & (temp_dat <= OUTLIER_MAX_THRESH)
    )
```

Now, you can map your function across all groups:

```
masked = da.tmax.groupby('time.month').map(simple_out)
```

Comment: I've been reviewing this some more and cannot understand if this does, then how it's working separately at each lat/lon pair separately. I get how the groupby 'time.month' works, but wouldn't only grouping by that mean simeple_out is being run across all lats and lons data for a single month at the same time? I was thinking I'd want to do something like 
`masked = da.tmax.groupby(['time.month', 'lat', 'lon']).map(simple_out)` but that gives the error: `TypeError: `group` must be an xarray.DataArray or the name of an xarray variable or dimension. Received ['time.month', 'lat', 'lon'] instead.`